# Am I a Secondary Taxicab?

Tags: code-golf, math, number, decision-problem

## Background

Ramanujan's number, \$1729\$, is called a [taxi-cab number](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number) due to the (possibly apocryphal) tale of Hardy boarding a cab to visit Ramanujan in hospital having this number, which seemed bland to him.

It's since known as the most famous of a class of integers known as "taxicab numbers" which are expressible as the sum of two \$n\$th powers (of positive integers) in two (or sometimes \$k\$) different ways.

\$1729\$ is the smallest natural number expressible as the sum of 2 cubes in 2 different ways, making it the first \$3,2\$ taxicab number (\$n,k\$ being general).

## Challenge

Given a number, decide whether it is a \$3,2\$ 'secondary taxicab number' - meaning it fulfils the same constraint as \$1729\$ (2 unique sums of cubes), but does not have to be the smallest such integer of the \$3,2\$ class (that being 1729, of course).

#### Example cases

$$1729 = 10^3 + 9^3 = 12^3 + 1^3 \\
4104 = 15^3 + 9^3 = 16^3 + 2^3 \\
13832 = 2^3 + 24^3 = 18^3 + 20^3$$

As well as \$20683, 32832, 39312...\$

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins.

---

Rough Matlab code to find other cases by brute force:

```
for k = 1729:20000
    C = sum(round(mod(real((k-[1:ceil(k^(1/3))].^3).^(1/3)),1)*10000)/10000==1);
    if C > 1
        D = (mod(C,2)==0)*C/2 + (mod(C,2)==1)*((C+1)/2);
        disp([num2str(k),' has ',num2str(D),' solns'])
    end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I edited your question a bit to make it a bit more clear. Would you be willing to add some test cases?

Comment: Yep, I was struggling because I'm at work and don't have Matlab, but managed to get Octave online to work and found 4104=16^3+4^3=15^3+9^3

Comment: 1729 sould be true or false?

Comment: True. All non-taxicabs false.

Comment: If 1729 is true, then can you explain (or alter/remove) `but is not the smallest such integer of the "3,2" class (that being 1729, of course)`? Thanks!

Comment: Good point, sorry about that!

Comment: As far as I can tell, the two answers interpreted the spec differently. Should **87539319 = 167³ + 436³ = 228³ + 423³ = 255³ + 414³** return true or false?

Comment: Yes, that should be a true, I could have clarified "3,2" as a sum of two cubes in "at least** two ways".

Comment: [A001235](https://oeis.org/A001235)

Comment: "Both men were mathematicians and liked to think about numbers." - This was the point I got to before I had to check whether I was on Simple English Wikipedia. Anyone else?

Comment: Do there need to be exactly two ways to write the number, or at least two?

Comment: someone should write an answer in Taxi https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

#### Code (very slow)

```
L3mãOQO3›
```

#### Code (much faster), 12 bytes

```
tL3mDδ+˜QO3›
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/xMc41@XcFu3TcwL9jR817Pr/39DcyBIA)

#### Explanation

```
t                # Square root (not necessary but added for speed)
 L               # Create a list [1 .. sqrt(input)]
  3m             # Raise to the power of 3
    D            # Duplicate
     δ+          # 2 dimensional addition
       ˜         # Deep-flatten the entire list
        Q        # Check which are equal to the input
         O       # Sum up to get the number of equalities
          3›     # Checks whether there are 4 or more equalities. In order for a number
                   to be a secondary taxicab number, there are at least two distinct
                   ways to get to that number and 4 ways when you also take reversed
                   arguments in account.
```

Comment: Surely you could save a byte by removing the square root. This is code-golf, not fastest-code.

Comment: @Christian I have added a slow version of the code.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

Credits to Erik the Outgolfer.

```
Œċ*3S€ċ>1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opCPdWsbBj5rWHOm2M/z//7@huZElAA)

This is too slow that it won't even work for `1729` online.

### Much faster, 12 bytes

Credits to Dennis.

```
R*3fRŒċS€ċ>1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9Iyzgt6OikI93Bj5rWHOm2M/z//7@huZElAA)

Comment: I just tested this with "4104" and it passed. :)
Haven't found any beyond this yet, but that was lightning fast!

Comment: `Ðf⁸` can become `fR`. The second `⁸` can be removed.

Comment: The second ⁸ can be removed indeed, but the fR swap leads to failure.

Comment: By the way, this is [tag:code-golf] so we don't care about speed ;) but you can still include the fast version in the TIO link.

Comment: You don't need to care about speed, just do `Œċ*3S€ċ>1`.

Comment: @DrQuarius Could you give me an example where `fR` fails? This keeps all cubes that are not greater than the input, which can't possibly be part of a valid sum.

Comment: @Dennis♦ I just find it fails even on 1729 when I replace  Ðf⁸ with fR... https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9Iy9gmLejopCPdwY@a1hzpftS4w87w////huZGlgA

Comment: PS @Leaky Nun, if you amend your answer to 11 bytes, I'll accept yours as the winner, since my MATL solution is 12 at best (as is the 05AB1E solution).

Comment: @DrQuarius done

Comment: @Dennis it's `<Ðf⁸` that can become `fR`, not just `Ðf⁸`.

Comment: @LeakyNun Right, my bad.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 35 bytes

```
Count[#^3+#2^3&~Array~{#,#},#,2]>2&
```

Pure function taking a positive integer and returning `True` or `False`.

`#^3+#2^3&~Array~{#,#}` tabulates all sums of cubes of two integers between 1 and the input. (This would be much faster with a sensible bound on the integers to be cubed, like the cube root of the input; but that would take precious bytes. As it is, the code takes about 30 seconds on the input `13832` and scales at least quadratically in the input.) `Count[...,#,2]` counts how many times the input appears in this list at nest-level 2; if this number is greater than `2`, then the input is a semi-taxicab number (greater than 2, rather than greater than 1, since a^3+b^3 and b^3+a^3 are being counted separately).

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```
Tr[1^PowersRepresentations[#,2,3]]>1&
```

*-1 byte thanks to @GregMartin*

As always, there is a Mathematica builtin to everything.

Comment: Assuming that the OP is ok with more-than-2-representations, then I believe `Tr[1^...]` works in place of `Length@`.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), 15 bytes

```apl
{4≤⍵⍧∘.+⍨3*⍨⍳⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfyf9qhtgsb/apNHnUse9W591Lv8UccMPe1HvSuMtYDEo97NQNHa/5r/0xQMzY0s/@sWAwA)

Same method as all the other answers. Only works till 4104 due to brute forcing.

more than 20 bytes golfed off with dzaima's help at the APL orchard.

The output appears with a ⊂ next to it, which has been patched in the latest version of the interpreter.

### Explanation

```apl
{4≤⍵⍧∘.+⍨3*⍨⍳⍵} ⍵ → input
         3*⍨⍳⍵  range 1 to n, cubed
     ∘.+⍨       dot product, addition with itself
   ⍵⍧           number of times ⍵ appears in the sums
 4≤             is 4 less than or equal to that?
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 48 bytes

```
Length@Solve[x^3+y^3-#==0<x<y,{x,y},Integers]>1&
```

**input**

> [4104]

**output**

> True

Comment: Note that `#!=1729&&` is no longer necessary now that the spec has been clarified.

Comment: Could you use `Solve` rather than `Reduce`?

Comment: of course...1 byte is 1 byte!

Comment: Can save one more byte with `Length@Solve[x^3+y^3-#==0<x<y,{x,y},Integers]>1&` which replaces the `&&` with `-` and a little bit of rearranging.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES7), 63 bytes

A relatively fast recursive function which eventually returns a boolean.

```js
f=(n,k,r=0,x=n-k**3)=>x<0?r>3:f(n,-~k,r+=(x**(1/3)+.5|0)**3==x)
```

#### Demo

```js
f=(n,k,r=0,x=n-k**3)=>x<0?r>3:f(n,-~k,r+=(x**(1/3)+.5|0)**3==x)

console.log([...Array(40000).keys()].filter(n => f(n)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATL (<strike>16</strike> 15 bytes) (<strike>13</strike> 12 ideally)

```
.4^:3^2XN!sG=sq
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X88kzso4zijCT7HY3ba48P9/Q3Mjy695@brJickZqQA)

### Explanation:

Based on the Jelly solution of 'Leaky Nun', just converted to MATL, probably redundant in some parts and can be improved:

```
.4^  % rough cube root of input, as maximum potential integer N.
:3^   % create array of all cubes from 1^3 up to N^3.
2XN   % do nchoosek on cube array, creating all possible pairs (k=2) to add.
!s    % transpose array and add all pairs to find sums.
G=    % find all pairs that equal the original input.
sq   % if there is more than one solution, then pass the test.
```

Note: falsy outputs include 0 and -1, while truthy output is 1. Thanks to Luis Mendo for saving an extra byte here replacing "s1>" with "sq".

### Ideally (<strike>13</strike> 12 bytes):

```
:3^2XN!sG=sq
```

...is enough, but for larger numbers this crashes on tio.run's page.

Comment: Original:
MATL (19 bytes)
===============
    XH.34^:3^2XN!sH=s1>

Comment: If any truthy output is valid, you can replace `1>` by `q`. Also, you have `H` instead of `G` in the explanation. The fact that the program crashes for large numbers is usually irrelevant for scoring. If it works given enough time and memory that's acceptable, unless the challenge specifies otherwise

Comment: Thanks Luis! I'm new to "truthy" outputs, but this works nicely now. Edited to amend. Also, thanks for creating such a fun and easy to use esolang!

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 71 bytes

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/rvYxvzPycxNyklUaHCKic1TyM6UyEtv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VaNCEySQhRDI1KnQzExTyNTSMtbOAhK2thWxmnaG/wuKMvNKFHw0DM2NLDX/AwA)

```python
lambda x:len([i for i in range(x)for j in range(i,x)if i**3+j**3==x])>1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 52 bytes

```ruby
->n{r=*1..n;r.product(r).count{|i,j|i**3+j**3==n}>1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9cur7rIVstQTy/PukivoCg/pTS5RKNIUy85vzSvpLomUyerJlNLy1g7C0jY2ubV2hnW/i/PyMxJVUhPLSnmUihQSItWidcryY/PjOVKzUv5b2JoYAIA)

Since this version creates a massive n<sup>2</sup> sized array, it fails on all true testcases higher than `1729`, here is a modified version that has a smaller array size of about n<sup>2/3</sup>, which successfully checks at least up to 31392.

[Try it online! (modified)](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9cur7rIVstQTy9PS8tAzxgITKyL9AqK8lNKk0s0ijT1kvNL80qqazJ1smoytbSMtbOAhK1tXq2dYe3/8ozMnFSF9NSSYi6FAoW0aJV4vZL8@MxYrtS8lP/GlsaGRgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 76 bytes

```php
for(;$i++<$argn**(1/3);)for($n=1;$n<$i;)$n++**3+$i**3!=$argn?:$c++;echo$c>1;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYrBDoMgEAXv/QvNOwibpiGkae1C/RazUeGyEP/dM7Ze5jAzNdUWpprqDfO@aezfr6cfvRt7bmvZB0YmClezdnAPb9j8PTQ6hgZkNlAiaz0h/9jFa54@ECJeJBXI13Frh5a7zJKWEw)

[Search till 400000 Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYq7DoJAEEV7/0IyIfsg6gYrB6QwFDbaWJqQDVlhm2EzYGX011fgFrc454Q@xKIKfdg45oEbdmHgyVMnfnVzuz@ul1ri5jWws20v2FLnhMmOh2XSjmC5I/l50@gmAT6DVmKca4HgtS5WrZQw@1yiXDhQaRCoAI8SSGulcg1@/m25xtUJWq0R2rNJ08CephXvkiclGL/xDw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pa`, 49 bytes

```perl
$_=1<grep{//;grep$'**3+$_**3=="@F",$_.."@F"}1..$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tbQJr0otaBaX98aRKuoa2kZa6vEA0lbWyUHNyUdlXg9PRCj1lBPTyX@/39DcyPLf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsScwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 32 bytes

```
D,g,@,3^AR3€Ω^$€+
L,R€gb+A€=b+2=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ13HQcc4zjHI@FHTmnMr41SAlDaXj04QkE5P0nYEUrZJ2ka2/6FCTm5OsXBBLi6VnMTcpJREBSM7Q1MDLn8UAXMjS1QRE0MDEy7//wA)

The Footer in the TIO link is simply a faster version (`b+` \$\to\$ `BFB]`)

### How it works

```
D,g,@,		; Define a helper function, g
		; It takes an int;	STACK = [5]
	3^	; Cube;			STACK = [125]
	AR	; Argument range;	STACK = [125 [1 2 3 4 5]]
	3€Ω^	; Cube each;		STACK = [125 [1 8 27 64 125]]
	$€+	; Add the cube to each;	STACK = [[126 133 152 189 250]]

L,		; Define the main function
		; Takes an int;		STACK = [1729]
	R	; Range;		STACK = [[1 2 3 ... 1728 1729]]
	€g	; Run g over each;	STACK = [[[2] [9 16] ... ]]
	b+	; Concatenate;		STACK = [[2 9 16 ...]]
	A€=b+	; Count argument;	STACK = [2]
	2=	; Equals 2?		STACK = [1]
```